# How can I get a list of the members currently in a Discord voice channel?

Tags: node.js, express, discord

The following code results in this error:

```
400
Error getting member list
Error: {"message":"Cannot execute action on this channel type","code":50024}
```

```
const endpoint = `https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/${channel_id}/thread-members`;
try {
  const res = await fetch(endpoint, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bot ${process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'User-Agent': 'DiscordBot (https://github.com/discord/discord-example-app, 1.0.0)',
    },
    method: 'GET'
  });
} catch (err) {
  console.error("Error getting member list");
  console.error(err)
}
```

How do I get a list of member objects that are currently in a voice channel? I apologize if I'm doing something really silly here, I am new to Discord development.

Edit -- context

I am trying to affect the execution of a slash command depending on who specifically is in a particular voice channel at the time the slash command is executed. The server nicknames of members who have access to this channel correspond to data in other services (google sheets and Firestore). To be clear I'm talking about members who are currently connected to the voice channel, not merely people who have access to it.